# change css in sortable jquery ui list isnot so simple?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my poor code : http://jsfiddle.net/jesspoub/gjDcd/

I'd like to have only the five first item of the list in blue color and all
other in red color . Actualy if you drag all item in "sortable1" , all items changes color .I need to keep only 5 first item position in blue color .
I'm newbe with jquery so any help will very appreciate..

```
                 <script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connectedSortable"}).disableSelection();});
                </script>
```

thx,
Jessica

Comment: see answer jess and rememeber to mark answers that work for you ;) that's the tick on the left of the answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gjDcd/5/)

```
$("#sortable1 li").addClass('green');
$("#sortable2 li").addClass('red');
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function () {
        var lis = $('#sortable1 li').add('#sortable2 li');
        $(lis).each(function () {
            if ($(this).index('li') <= 4) {
                $(this).removeClass('red ui-state-highlight').addClass('green ui-state-default');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('green ui-state-default').addClass('red ui-state-highlight');
            }
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: boththanks guys ! both solutions work , don"t know what's its better :d

Answer (score 0):

Use `:lt` and `:gt` selectors, add / remove color `class` on `sortable` `update` like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        update: function() {
            $('li:lt(5)').removeClass('color1 color2').addClass('color1');
            $('li:gt(4)').removeClass('color1 color2').addClass('color2');
        }
    }).disableSelection();

    $('li:lt(5)').addClass('color1');
    $('li:gt(4)').addClass('color2');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/gjDcd/2/)**

Comment: thanks guys ! both solutions work , don"t know what's its better

Comment: all solutions works , don't know whats its better but many thanks for the help and explanations  jessica

Comment: Glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted (pun) your problem.

Basically I just used css to style the list using the 'next sibling' in conjunction with first-child psuedo selector and a rule with 5 levels.

See [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjDcd/3/)

And Css is:

```
 #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
 margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 width: 160px;
 color:red;
 }

 #sortable1 li:first-child,
 #sortable1 li:first-child+li, 
 #sortable1 li:first-child+li+li, 
 #sortable1 li:first-child+li+li+li, 
 #sortable1 li:first-child+li+li+li+li {
 color:green
 }
```

Comment: And if you want to be a real smart arse you could use `#container>ul[id=*'sortable']:first-child` instead of `#sortable1` to apply the rule to the first ul just in case you were swapping list poistions round in the DOM.

Comment: all solutions works , don't know whats its better but many thanks for the help and explanations  jessica